# How to perform Apache 2 config migration from Linux SUSE to Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu, apache2, suse

I'm a newbie with Apache configurations. I need to migrate a web tool running on Linux SUSE with Apache 2 to Ubuntu. It is currently using an external *httpd.conf* located in some other place on the machine, set as **APACHE_HTTPD_CONF** variable in `/etc/sysconfig/apache2`. It looks like there is no `/etc/sysconfig/apache2`, and also no **APACHE_HTTPD_CONF** variable in any of the files in `/etc/apache2/` on Ubuntu.
How can I configure it correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ubuntu, at **/etc/apache2** you have the possibility to config several criteria of things, such as:

- conf
- mods
- sites

These have a folder of **-available** (**sites-available**, for example) and a folder of **-enabled** (**sites-enabled**, for example). You will definitely need to define your **sitename.conf** file in **sites-available** and then run

```
sudo a2ensite sitename
```

to enable it. Similarly, you will need to enable mods and conf. Whenever you performed some large change and intend to test or use Apache, restart it:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

There is also an **apache2.conf** file for general Apache settings.

In your scenario I would recommend copying the content of your httpd.conf into **/etc/apache2/sites-available/sitename.conf** and then run

```
sudo a2ensite sitename
sudo service apache2 restart
```

This copies the config file from **/etc/apache2/sites-available** to **/etc/apache2/sites-enabled** and restarts Apache. You will also need to edit **/etc/hosts** to define your sitename to be loaded from 127.0.0.1.